# Python: Compare String to whole next column

Tags: python, pandas, string-comparison

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1:
       2000 2001 2002 
        a    a     a 
        b    b     c
        c    c     d
```

So, in 2002 the value b got replaced by c. What I want now is for every column, to check whether each value of the column, i.e. for a, b, and c separately, is a member of the next column. Then, I would like to have an output for a,b,c and d indicating the date when the string became first a member and a date it stopped to be a member. Like this:

```
df2: 
      a       b       c     d
      2000   2000   2000   2002
      NaN    2002   Nan    NaN
```

Can anybody help me how to achieve this in python?

Edit: This is how I would start, but I don't know how to implement it in python.

```
 for c in columns: 
     for v in column:
         drop v if v is not in c_[+1] 
 remove all empty columns
```

In theory, this should give me a dataframe showing only the dates with the removed values. E.g:

```
  df2: 
  2002 
   b
```

I would then do a similar analysis but for the values that got added and then merge the two dataframes. However, I don't know how to exactly convert each column to a list and check whether v is part of that list and then go to the next column.

Comment: Do you have an attempt at a solution?

Comment: Is this for homework? Not sure if I should write an algorithm for you..

Comment: No, this is not for homework. I added an attempt above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful tool to look at here is `pd.DataFrame().stack()`:

```
df1.stack()
Out[24]: 
0  2000    a
   2001    a
   2002    a
1  2000    b
   2001    b
   2002    c
2  2000    c
   2001    c
   2002    d
dtype: object
```

Because your column names sort nicely, you can sort this and then use `drop_duplicates()` to get:

```
df1.stack().sort_index(level=1).drop_duplicates()
Out[26]: 
0  2000    a
1  2000    b
2  2000    c
   2002    d
dtype: object
```

or

```
df1.stack().sort_index(level=1).drop_duplicates(keep='last')
Out[28]: 
1  2001    b
0  2002    a
1  2002    c
2  2002    d
dtype: object
```

To convert these to give years indexed by value, instead of values by year, you can add `.reset_index().set_index(0)['level_1']` to either of these:

```
start = df1.stack().sort_index(level=1).drop_duplicates().reset_index().set_index(0)['level_1']
start
Out[31]: 
0
a    2000
b    2000
c    2000
d    2002
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

After also doing this for the other, call it `end`, you can use `pd.Series().map()` on a dictionary constructed from the columns, to get the name of the first one where the value does not appear, instead of the last where it does.

```
cols = df1.columns.tolist()+[np.nan]
next_col = {cols[i]:cols[i+1] for i in range(len(cols)-1)}
end = end.map(next_col)
end
Out[36]: 
0
b    2002
a     NaN
c     NaN
d     NaN
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

To then combine these to create `df2`, you can use `pd.concat`:

```
df2 = pd.concat([start, end], axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)

df2
Out[40]: 
      a     b     c     d
0  2000  2000  2000  2002
1   NaN  2002   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Wow. This works really great, but only with the start values, i.e. with the 0 index in df2. The end value is always the next column. For example I get the following result a: 2000, 2001 b: 2000 2001, c: 2000, 2001....

Am I right that I just do the SAME procedure for end as for start? because after having ran `start = df1.stack().sort_index(level=1).drop_duplicates().reset_index().set_index(0)['level_1']` I do `end = start ` and execute the rest.

Comment: The error is probably that in `next_col = {cols[i]:cols[i+1] for i in range(len(cols)-1)}` the `cols[I+1] refers only to the next cell. I would probably need a [last column] command right?

Comment: `end` is almost the same as `start`, except you keep the last duplicate after sorting instead of the first. That's what the `keep='last'` argument in `.drop_duplicates(keep='last')` in `end` is about. You could get a similar result by passing `ascending=False` to `.sort_index()` for `end`, though I figured it was better to give the option to store the sorted stacked dataframe as an intermediate step. `nextcol` should only refer to the next cell – otherwise, even with `keep='last'`, `end` pulls the last column where the value shows up, rather than the first column where it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

General algorithm:

1) Group data into lists by year. `lzts = [['2000', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['2001', 'a', 'b', 'c'], etc]`

2) Create function to loop through lists, searching for instance of given value.

```
def search(val):
  ans = (float('NaN'), float('NaN')) #start & end date for given value
  for lzt in lzts:
    if val in lzt[1:]: #skip first value since its the year
      if math.isnan(ans[0]): #no start date yet
        ans[0] = lzt[0] #add the year
    else: #value not found
      if not math.isnan(ans[0]): #already has start date 
        ans[1] = lzt[0] #add the year as end date
```

NOTE: This solution assumes that once a value stops appearing for a year, it is gone forever. If a value was to not appear for a year and then return, the results would be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Parse each column into a list and then go from there.

```
input = ''' 2000 2001 2002 
        a    a     a 
        b    b     c
        c    c     d '''

lines = []
for line in input.split('\n'):
    print ' '.join(line.split())
    lines.append(line.split())

print lines
```

output:

```
[['2000', '2001', '2002'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'd']]
```